# Encoding information into a link in html to be used by the target

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

Very new to programming/coding in general, so feel free to answer with just a link if this question is a bit simple.

I'm currently creating a website with a searchable database using almost exclusively html, css, and php. I have the search parameters page, which leads to a results page. I want to be able to click on one of those individual results to give me detailed information about that result. (Think something like Magic: the Gathering's Gatherer, with an image, and all sorts of details that wouldn't fit in a table.)

I have a page set up with the layout I want, but I'm unsure how to provide the information required to the page from just a link. Each field in my database has a unique ID number, so I just need the correct but of code to insert I assume into just the `<a href="">` section, similar to a title. I've looked on the html manual and used W3 schools, but I don't find any such function. I have also looked at a bunch of questions on here about html links but didn't find any. (And there's a lot, so I could've missed one, I'm sure.)

I would prefer a solution that worked with either php or html code, ideally. I have seen other projects that use js and ruby, and would like to avoid them if possible for this project.

Please let me know if there's any more information I could provide.

Comment: Its called an [Anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) `<a href="a_php_script.php?p1=1&p2=44">Click me and I will do magic</a>`

Comment: So in this example you've given I have the link alongside:

a_php_script.php: The actual php link I need to call. (ie the one I created)
"?p1=1&p2=44": Here I would replace the p's with the variables I want and the numbers (=1/=44) with the appropriate variables?

Comment: Errr, yes I think so

Comment: Sorry, the formatting broke when I clicked post on that comment. I'm giving it a shot now assuming I understand what you said. <_<

Comment: All working! Thank you very much! :D